# Check if Parental control is active on Amazon device

Tags: android

I'm trying to find a way to check if parental control is enabled on an Amazon device.
I've tried this code

```
DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(
             Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

//this active admin is 
//com.amazon.tv.parentalcontrols/com.amazon.tv.parentalcontrols.PCONAdminReceiver
boolean isActive = devicePolicyManager.isAdminActive
    (devicePolicyManager.getActiveAdmins().get(0));
```

But this doesn't work and isActive is always true even when Parental Control is disabled.

Is there a way to achieve this with standard permissions?

Comment: have you added MANAGE_DEVICE_ADMINS permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code

```
import android.provider.Settings;

public class ParentalControlChecker {

    public static boolean isParentalControlEnabled() {
        
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

        
        int parentalControlSetting = Settings.Secure.getInt(contentResolver, "parental_control_enabled", 0);

        
        return parentalControlSetting == 1;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind to update your AndroidManifest.xml file with the required permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

If parental control is enabled, the method isParentalControlEnabled() will return true; otherwise, it will return false.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, honestly i don't know how Amazon implements the parental control. But just two thoughts, maybe it helps a bit to get forward:

- In the given code, you call the list of active admins and then check, if the first admin is active. Logically, your `isActive` is always true, since you check `isAdminActive` on a list-item out of only activated admins. However, this procedure should also throw you an error if there are no active admins given, since the resulting `null` value is not allowed on `isAdminActive`.
- Did you check, if Amazon does really use the activation of device admins? I could imagine, that they just register one 'amazon'-admin on your device, while then handling the parental access within their own code. This could mean, that the android-amazon-admin is just always active, no matter which rights you set within amazon.